# snowflake - query grants to role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I made all table grants to a role:

```
grant select on all tables in               schema WORKING to role PROD_WORKING_SR;
grant select on all views  in               schema WORKING to role PROD_WORKING_SR;
grant select on future tables in            schema WORKING to role PROD_WORKING_SR;
grant select on future views  in            schema WORKING to role PROD_WORKING_SR;
```

but when I try to verify the grants using command:

```
show grants to role PROD_WORKING_SR
```

I get nothing. Can someone help me with a query that I can extract all privileges granted to a role like I did above.

Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Could you try `grants on` instead of `grants to`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give USAGE privilege to the role for database and schema

You can do this using

```
grant usage on database <your db name> to role PROD_WORKING_SR;
grant usage on schema WORKING to role PROD_WORKING_SR;
```